# Is there a verb and analogous noun similar to ‘to greet’ and 'greeter' used when people depart?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

I am looking for words analogous to ‘to greet’ and ‘greeter’, to use about people as they depart. I may say:

*Claire stands at the entrance and greets people as they arrive. She is a greeter.*

I want to say:

*Sam stands at the exit and ??? people as they leave. He is a ???.*

I have found the word ‘valediction’, which is defined as ‘the action of saying farewell’, but I cannot find anything that means ‘the person who performs valediction’. There does not seem to be a verb ‘to valedict’.

What words (verb and analogous noun) best describe Sam’s role?

Comment: Wiktionary has **fareweller** which is probably the closest you can get to having a word meaning "someone who says goodbye to people", though obviously it isn't in a proper dictionary.

Comment: "Glad you leave !" or "Happy to get rid of U !" :O) (Valediction means bye for ever we won't meet again before Inferno)

Comment: Sam is accepting the thank-yous of his guests as they leave.  It's standard socially at some events to thank the host (and/or hostess) as one leaves and say whatever else there is to say.

Comment: @JJJ  Clearly, the OP wanted a verb AND its derived noun equivalent. Part is the verb, but "parter" does not work the same way as "greeter" does.

Comment: @Mari-LouA you are right, I have edited the question to better reflect that.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not one of the close voters :S, I think I flagged it before I could vote for closure.

Comment: But the possible duplicate link was posted by you. That's why I pinged you. Now your old comment (dated 29/30 march?) has gone. In the meantime, there are still three votes that are saying this question is a duplicate. It's not.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I deleted the comment because it wasn't a duplicate (as you pointed out). I am not one of the close voters, I just got that privilege today (so my flag was merely an indicator for others). I'll just up vote your comment so its clear to future reviewers that it's not a duplicate.

Comment: The word *greeter* is usually used for those whose *job* is to greet people. Are there really people whose job is to say 'good bye' (and whose job is not to also greet them when arriving)?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a suitable one word to use as a verb other than "bid farewell". Oxford Online Dictionary mentions that to [*farewell*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/farewell) is used as a transitive verb in Australian and New Zealand English as in:

> I **farewelled** my Scandinavian companions, and departed on a Kodiak boat
>   with the Americans Judy, Hank and Cody.

For the noun, you could consider [good-byer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/good-byer) which means:

> A person who is saying goodbye.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Answer (score 1):

It's not what you were looking for, but Sam can be described as the

**[host](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/host?s=t)** or **[doorman](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/doorman?s=t)**

> host:
>
> 1. a person who receives or entertains guests at home or elsewhere:
>      the host at a theater party.
> 2. a master of ceremonies, moderator, or interviewer for a television or radio program.

[Emily Post says](http://emilypost.com/advice/party-etiquette-tips-for-hosts-and-guests/)

> Six Ways to Be a Good Host
>
> 6) Be appreciative. Thank people for coming as you bid them good-bye. And don’t forget to thank anyone who brought you a gift.

> doorman: the door attendant of an apartment house, nightclub, etc., who acts as doorkeeper and may perform minor services for entering and departing residents or guests.

The verb is easier.

**[take leave](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/take-leave-of)**

> (Also, take one's leave of) Depart from, say good-bye to. *Sorry but I have to take leave of you now.  After the movie we'll take our leave of you. [Mid-1200s ]*

Answer (score -1):

I would like to propose extending the word *valediction* (the action of saying farewell) to the new forms of *valedictate* and *valedictator*.

*The valedictator valedictated valedictions to the parting guests.*

Answer (score -1):

valediction-
N. an act of bidding farewell

valedictory-
Adj. of or relating to a valediction : expressing or containing a farewell
N. an address or statement of farewell or leave-taking

valedictorian-
N. person who delivers the valediction

Comment: Hi, welcome to EL&U.  Please cite your references; your  definition of *valedictorian* could be misleading.  I encourage you to take a [tour] of the site and see the [help] to keep contributing.  What verb would you use?

Comment: This term is normally used for something far more elaborate than what the OP has in mind.